# NetSuite Suite script - all columns for object

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there a function in Suitescript using which we would get all the fields or columns belonging to the object (i.e. location, account, transaction etc.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function getAllFields() of the record to retrieve all the fields for that record.

```javascript
var fields = nlapiGetNewRecord().getAllFields()
 // loop through the returned fields
 fields.forEach(function(fieldName){
    var field = record.getField(fieldName);
    
    var fieldlabel =  field.getLabel();
    if(fieldlabel=='something'){
       //do something here
       return;
    }
 }
```

you can also get the list of available fields for a record [here](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/RecordsBrowser/2012_2/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Can you please let us know how can we retrieve the list of columns defined in saved search. We tried nlapiLoadRecord.getColumns(), but it give error when we try to use the script in our windows application. Also when we debug the script on the Netsuite online debugger, it gives an error saying method not specified.

Comment: The reason you're getting that error is because getAllColumns() is a member of the nlobjSearchResult object, and nlapiSearchRecord() returns an array of nlobjSearchResult.

To get it to work, just use results[index].getAllColumns().